# How can Ioad all Images into an imagelist from a specific folder in c#

Tags: c#

How can I load all `Images` into an image list from a specific folder in c#? thanks!

```
List<Texture2D> images = new List<Texture2D>();
string folderPath = "MyImages/";
for(int i= 0; i<Count; i++) { 
    try{  
        images.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>(folderPath + i.ToString));}
    catch{break;}
}
```

This works but I need to convert the filenames into 1 to N. But I have to keep the filenames(the name of the personImage) for future use (for recognition output).

Comment: What have you tried? You should make your research first, try something and then if you have any problem post it here.

Comment: @JadeIxiann - Small tip: you can always [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14307130/edit) to add more information). FYI, your last comment was merged into the original question for better readability. So you can delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the image paths, you could try like this:

```
public List<String> GetAllImages(String directory)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach, in this case: (Don't forget to add using System.IO)

Here, set the folder to the DirectoryInfo

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
```

To get the right files you have to specify the type, i'm using jpg but can be png, bmp etc.

```
FileInfo[] Archives = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

Now, for each archive in the folder it will add to imagelist

```
foreach (FileInfo fileinfo in Archives)
{
  imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(fileinfo.FullName));
}
```

I've tested, worked. Alright?